# docker create network error: not permitted

Tags: docker, networking

detail errors info below:

```
[root@tcs-10-0-114-9 ~]# docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
9e953d74c92e        host                host                local
a90338bd0bf4        none                null                local
[root@tcs-10-0-114-9 ~]# docker network create --driver=bridge bridge
Error response from daemon: operation is not permitted on predefined bridge network
[root@tcs-10-0-114-9 ~]#
```

for the errrors, in root user privileges,but it does stil stuck.

Comment: That network should be included by default. How and why was it deleted in your environment? Did you try restarting the docker engine?

Comment: Please update the question with the command and configuration used to start the engine, and include `/etc/docker/daemon.json`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, no `bridge` network created after installing docker.

Update the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` from `"bridge": "none"` to `"bridge": ""` and then restart docker `systemctl restart docker`

```
{
    "bridge": "",
    "graph": "/var/lib/docker",
    "group": "pf9group",
    "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"],
    "live-restore": true,
    "log-driver": "json-file",
    "log-opts": {
        "max-size": "10m",
        "max-file": "10"
    },
    "storage-driver": "",
    "storage-opts": [ ],
    "debug": false,
    "registry-mirrors": [],
    "default-gateway": ""
}
```

Issue was fixed

```
# docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME      DRIVER    SCOPE
ab91d4e7dc9f   bridge    bridge    local
aa6a59551185   host      host      local
fba73c551170   none      null      local
```